# how to exclude some urls in android applink pathprefix

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

intent

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data
          android:scheme="https"
          android:host="url.com" 
          />
        </intent-filter>
```

Website URLs look like the following

```
url.com/usernames  //website users username open in app
url.com/brand/..  //open in app
url.com/data/.. // open in app


url.com/about/.. // exclude
url.com/privacy/..// exclude
```

How can I manage not to open some URLs with the app?

Comment: There is another data property you might add to the filter where you can specify one or more pathPrefix
`<data android:pathPrefix="/usernames">`
`<data android:pathPrefix="/brand">`
`...`
Starting slash is required and I don't know if wildcards can be used.
So you could add the ones you want to allow.
I don't know if you're aware of the slight difference between direct links and app links. Anyway, it seems to me that this prefix filter only applies to direct links (hoping I'm wrong).
Please let us know if you figure that out.